# Hourly, Daily, Monthly Helper+Model methods

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-web-api

I have a web portal, parsing the API, to a web URL, where it goes through JSON.

This data is configured using Charts and we are currently using flot.js

The code for the hourlyData is already there and gets plugged into the json charts.

I'm trying to recreate this for Monthly and Yearly.

The current code for hourlyData looks like this:

```
  List<dynamic> hourlyData = new List<dynamic>();
            DateTime hourIterator = StartDate.Value;
            while (hourIterator.Hour <= ddvm.CurrentHour)
            {
                if (ddvm.HourlyPaymentTotal != null && ddvm.HourlyPaymentTotal.Count() > 0 )
                {
                    HourlyPaymentTotalModel hour = ddvm.HourlyPaymentTotal.FirstOrDefault(hpt => hpt.DateTimeStamp == hourIterator);
                    if (hour == null) { hour = new HourlyPaymentTotalModel() { DateTimeStamp = hourIterator }; };
                    hourlyData.Add(new List<dynamic> {hourIterator.Hour,
                                                        hour.Amount, 
                                                        new { tooltip = String.Format("{0} : {1}", hour.Count, hour.Amount.ToString("C")) } });
                }
                hourIterator = hourIterator.AddHours(1);
            }

            ddvm.GraphData.LineChart_HourlyTotal.Add(new
            {
                data = hourlyData,
                color = "#A1345E",
                label = "Total Amount Paid"
            });
```

How can I recreate hourlyData into  monthlyData and yearlyData?

Edit:

```
    public class HourlyPaymentTotalModel : ViewModelBase
    {
        public int Hour 
        {
            get { return DateTimeStamp.Hour; }
            set { DateTimeStamp  = new DateTime(1, 1, 1, value, 0, 0); } 
        }
        public string FormattedHour
        {
            get { return DateTimeStamp.ToShortTimeString().Replace(":00 ", ""); }
            set { DateTimeStamp = DateTime.Parse(value); }
        }
        public DateTime DateTimeStamp { get; set; }
        public decimal Amount { get; set; }
        public int Count { get; set; }
    }
}
```

This is from the API solution:

```
public IQueryable<PaymentSummary> GetHourlyPaymentTotals(DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate, string PaymentProcessor = null, string merchantID=null)
        {
            transactionRepository = GetTransactionRepository(PaymentProcessor);
            IQueryable<IPayment> allPayments = transactionRepository.GetAllPayments(startDate, endDate, merchantID);
            var retVal = from ap in allPayments
                         group ap by new
                         {
                             PaymentDateYear = ap.PaymentDate.Value.Year,
                             PaymentDateMonth = ap.PaymentDate.Value.Month,
                             PaymentDateDay = ap.PaymentDate.Value.Day,
                             PaymentDateHour = ap.PaymentDate.Value.Hour
                         }
                             into grp_ap
                             select (new
                             {
                                 PaymentDateString = grp_ap.Key.PaymentDateMonth.ToString() + "/" + grp_ap.Key.PaymentDateDay.ToString() + "/" + grp_ap.Key.PaymentDateYear.ToString() + " " + grp_ap.Key.PaymentDateHour + ":00",
                                 Amount = grp_ap.Sum(grp => grp.Amount),
                                 Count = grp_ap.Count()
                             });
            return (IQueryable<PaymentSummary>)retVal.ToList().Select(p => new PaymentSummary()
            {
                PaymentDate = (DateTime?)DateTime.Parse(p.PaymentDateString),
                Amount = p.Amount,
                Count = p.Count
            }).ToList().AsQueryable();
        }
```

---

Update:  I created more models based on the solution Mairaj Ahmad proposed.
This is using the dailyData model.

I'm still not sure why the `<canvas>` is showing a blank under my chart fields. 
This is probably an error with the data or the flot.js options made to the specified charts.

```
var  area_chart_payment_by_day_options = {
        series: {
            lines: {
                show: true,
                fill: .5
            },
            points: { show: true }
        },
        grid: {
            borderWidth: 0,
            hoverable: true
        },
        tooltip: true,
        tooltipOpts: {
            content: "%x : $ %y"
        },
        xaxis: {
            //mode: "categories",
            tickDecimals: 0,
            min:1,
            max:31
        },
        yaxis: {
            tickFormatter: function (y) { return "$ " + y + " "; },
            tickDecimals:0
        }
    }
```

data function

```
 $(function () {
            var data = [];
            @Html.Raw("data = " + Json.Encode(Model.GraphData.LineChart_DailyTotal) + ";");   //TODO: LineChart_Daily
            $.plot($("#area_chart_payment_by_day"), area_chart_payment_by_day,
```

update function

```
$.plot($("#area_chart_payment_by_day"), area_chart_payment_by_day, area_chart_payment_by_day_options);
```

Comment: Can you show us your models?  Is there any reason you could group by hour and aggergate the sum of the amount between those times?

Comment: edit added, the dates are grouped together inside the hour model where the api solution is.

Comment: Are you using [tag:asp.net-mvc]?

Comment: have you checked the console for an error?

Answer (score 4):

You can create daily,monthly and yearly data by using the same logic. You just have to replace Hour with Day,Month or Year.

```
List<dynamic> dailyData = new List<dynamic>();
        DateTime dayIterator = StartDate.Value;
        while (dayIterator.Hour <= ddvm.CurrentDay)
        {
            if (ddvm.DailyPaymentTotal != null && ddvm.DailyPaymentTotal.Count() > 0 )
            {
                DailyPaymentTotalModel day = ddvm.DailyPaymentTotal.FirstOrDefault(hpt => hpt.DateTimeStamp == dayIterator);
                if (day == null) { hour = new DailyPaymentTotalModel() { DateTimeStamp = dayIterator }; };
                dailyData.Add(new List<dynamic> {dayIterator.Day,
                                                    day.Amount, 
                                                    new { tooltip = String.Format("{0} : {1}", day.Count, day.Amount.ToString("C")) } });
            }
            dayIterator = dayIterator.AddDays(1);
        }

        ddvm.GraphData.LineChart_DailyTotal.Add(new
        {
            data = dailyData,
            color = "#A1345E",
            label = "Total Amount Paid"
        });
```

And this will be your DailyModel.

```
public class DailyPaymentTotalModel : ViewModelBase
{
    public int Day 
    {
        get { return DateTimeStamp.Day; }
        set { DateTimeStamp  = new DateTime(1, 1, value, 0, 0, 0); } 
    }

    public DateTime DateTimeStamp { get; set; }
    public decimal Amount { get; set; }
    public int Count { get; set; }
}
```

}

And you data fetching logic looks to be in this function you need to make changes in it accordingly to make it work with day,month,year

```
transactionRepository.GetAllPayments(startDate, endDate, merchantID);
```

Comment: I changed   `while (dayIterator.Hour <= ddvm.CurrentDay)`  to `while (dayIterator.Day <= ddvm.CurrentDay)` And now I'm currently seeing a canvas where the chart should be but it's not displaying anything.

Comment: And have you changed the logic of getting data from DB on basis of days? It looks in the method getallpayments.